# Regex for URL path match not working. How to allow certain routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express

I am using this regex in my router

```
/^\/(?!api|mailAction(\/|\?))(.*)$/
```

as the router allows only `api/` or `api?` or `mailAction/` or `mailAction?`

Now the router is set as following -

```
app.get(/^\/(?!api|mailAction(\/|\?))(.*)$/, (req, res) => {
            console.log('not matched')
            if (req.isMobile) {
                return res.sendFile(path.join(FE.APP_PATH, "dist", "mob", this.clientName, "index.html"));
            } else {
                return res.sendFile(path.join(FE.APP_PATH, "dist", "web", this.clientName, "index.html"));
            }
        });
```

Still when the URL is `http://fe.localhost:4000/mailAction?t=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXfVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbklkIjo2MywiaWF0IjoxNTg0MDE4NjE2LCJleHAiOjE1ODQwNTQ2MTZ9.mCKwrMN2ppLlEMSp4U1_AwmNLDOjplOmnYTaFADf6FQ&a=ACT00000205` it serves the index.html file as written in middleware. I am not able to understand why. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried like this (without negative lookahead)?

`^\/(api|mailAction)(.*)$`

Comment: I want to serve index.html only when it doesn't match api or mailAction. That's why I used negative lookahead.

Comment: What about `(?!^\/(api|mailAction)(.*)$)`?